# Application of Page Rank Function in R on a Null Node

Tags: r, igraph

I tried the Page Rank function on a normal matrix with no Null Node. The ith row shows the node and the jth column shows the transition. So Matrix[i,j] denotes the transition from the ith row to the jth column

[Transition Matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UkT5Y.png)

```
library(igraph)
#-----B is the matrix----#
g2<-graph_from_adjacency_matrix(B, mode = "directed" , weighted = TRUE) 
plot(g2)

B1<-page.rank(g2, damping = 1)$vector
C1<-as.data.frame(B1)
```

This gave me the result(no damping):

The PageRank comes out to be `(3/9, 2/9, 2/9, 2/9)`

Now, I applied the same to another matrix with the Null node:

[New Matrix with 3rd Row being the Null node](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UjTvj.png)

What I should get is a row vector of 0,0,0,0 but what I get on using the function is:

The PageRank comes out to be `(0.2, 0.2666666,0.2666666,0.2666666)`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand PageRank it is not defined when there are nodes with an out-degree of zero (as you have here). According to this answer to a related question: [How does pageranking algorithm deal with webpage without outbound links?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21507375/how-does-pageranking-algorithm-deal-with-webpage-without-outbound-links) this is commonly dealt with by connecting the offending node to all of the others (including itself) with equal probability.

I tried this out with your example

```
B1 <- structure(c(0, 0.5, 0.25, 0, 0.333333333333333, 0, 0.25, 0.5, 
                  0.333333333333333, 0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.333333333333333, 0.5, 0.25, 
                  0), .Dim = c(4L, 4L))
g1 <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(B1, mode = "directed", weighted = TRUE)
page_rank(g1, damping = 1)$vector
```

and this gives

```
[1] 0.2000000 0.2666667 0.2666667 0.2666667
```

which is the same as you have.

[Updated from comments]
Under the hood `igraph` is using prpack so this must be accounting for nodes with zero out degree. If you want to flag up the problem before you run the `page_rank` function you could just check for:

```
any(degree(g1, mode = "out") == 0)
```

so actually get the zero vector that you want and preserve node names it could be something like:

```
outdeg <- degree(g1, mode = "out")
if (any(outdeg==0)) {
  B2 <- 0*outdeg
} else {
  B2 <- page_rank(g1, damping = 1)
}
```

or even smaller

```
B2 <- any(degree(g1, mode = "out") == 0) * page_rank(g1, damping = 1)
```

Comment: FWIW if you can pull apart the C code I think the magic is happening here: https://github.com/igraph/igraph/blob/19946d044c4b6ad7aa6f917d312453a83d8a7e6d/src/centrality.c#L937

Comment: R/igraph actually uses prpack by default, it is here: https://github.com/igraph/igraph/tree/master/src/prpack But yes, AFAIR zero out-degree node are worked around.

Comment: I still don't understand how to get the 0,0,0,0 matrix? Sorry. I am new to this. Never done coding before this.

Comment: If you want to catch the problem and make sure that you get the zero vector then something like `B2 <- any(degree(g1, mode = "out") == 0) * page_rank(g1, damping = 1)` (have updated the answer to include this and a longer version). There's no way that I know to have the `page_rank` function actually return a zero vector.